# React rendering in IE8

Tags: performance, internet-explorer-8, reactjs, rendering

I have an issue with a React webapp in IE8. The performance is fine in up to date versions of Chrome and FF. But, wouldn't you know it , the client runs IE8 and the app loads views very slowly in this browser , with 4 second load times normal. 
I profile the app using in IE8 with  IE8 Developer tools (IE8 running in VirtualBox VM).
In the generated call tree two code areas take, on average , **2 seconds**  each.
Drilling down into these codes I find React rendering methods such as mountComponent, mountChildren and createContentMarkup. There is a long long tree of these calls with relatively small amounts of time (100-300 ms) taken up with successive MountComponent calls.

It seems as if composite components added to the view are taking a long time to be added to the DOM, surprising for React.

Does anyone have any experience with the same situation, I am unsure how to proceed , except dismantle the composite components added and test for where the problem lies

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is reading this , then the only answer I came to was simplify your components. Use less nested components, reduce complexity, only render stuff when required using states , even replace complex components (nested lists) with a simple button which when clicked reveals the nested list (if that makes sense).
Most of all IE8 really didn't seem to be able to handle crunching lots of React updating /rendering / mounting code. So simplify your UI design e.g. tabs not all the information in one view  and reduce the complexity of the components.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try serverside rendering. If you render the components on the server, the load time will be less noticeable by the user

Comment: Yes that's a good point , unfortunately, due to project constraints,  it isn't an option in my case .